# Moving files accidentally to an not existing directory erases files?

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I moved all files from one directory using `mv` and accidentally made a typo in the target location path.

The system returned a message that the directory does not exists, but my files from source directory got erased.

Is that a bug? Should moving files to a nonexistent location erase the files being moved? (This is on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.)

---

The specifics were:

1. Created `test.txt` file.
2. Moved the file to `/ben` with `sudo`.
3. The file disappeared. `/ben` does not exist.

The commands and output were:

```
ben.b@c-w46:~/Desktop/test-folder$ sudo mv test.txt /ben
ben.b@c-w46:~/Desktop/test-folder$ cd /ben
bash: cd: /ben: Not a directory
```

Comment: In your case you renamed `test.txt` to `/ben`, so indeed `/ben` is not a directory (it is the new `file.txt`).

Comment: Why would it rename if I used mv ?

Comment: Because that's how `mv` works.

Comment: So how can I find that test.txt? or' its gone forever?

Comment: @benberizovsky Just access the file in `/`, as `/ben`. You can move it back, for example. I've posted an answer covering that and also the more general topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the command you actually ran, you didn't lose anything! It succeeded at renaming `test.txt` to `/ben`. Assuming `test.txt` was a regular file, so is the new `/ben` (they're the same file, after all).

The reason you see `bash: cd: /ben: Not a directory` is what it says on the tin: `/ben` is not a directory. You can still access the file.

If you want to avoid that sort of mistake and force `mv` to fail if the destination isn't a directory, write a trailing `/` on it or use `-t dir`. For example, any of these would've prevented the (very minor!) problem you experienced (with `sudo` as necessary):

```bash
mv test.txt /ben/  # no action, unless `/ben` is an existing directory
```

```bash
mv -t /ben test.txt  # same deal, -t doesn't accept regular-file operands
```

```bash
mv -t /ben/ test.txt  # you can even do both if you want
```

Information about the general situation described in your question--about losing files by attempting to move them--and what can and can't go wrong follows.

---

As [Rinzwind says](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160944/22949), moving files to a nonexistent destination directory shouldn't cause data loss when you attempt it using a single `mv` command. But it could happen if you ran `mv` more than once, such as in a shell loop.

For example, suppose I have:

```bash
ek@Apok:~/tmp$ ls -F
dest/       file02.txt  file04.txt  file06.txt  file08.txt  file10.txt
file01.txt  file03.txt  file05.txt  file07.txt  file09.txt
```

To move all those files into `dest`, I *should* pass all their names to `mv`, in a command like `mv file*.txt dest/` or `mv file*.txt dest`. In either case--that is, whether or not I write the target directory name with a trailing slash--this does the right thing. And in either case, if I misspell the target directory name (say, by writing `dst` instead) I get an error `mv: target 'dst' is not a directory` and no data are lost.

However, suppose I were to misspell `dst`, omit the trailing `/`, and run multiple `mv` commands. That would be bad, because when the destination of `mv` is a regular file, `mv` *replaces* it!

```bash
ek@Apok:~/tmp$ mv file01.txt dst  # bad if dst exists but isn't a directory
ek@Apok:~/tmp$ mv file02.txt dst  # bad, I just lost the old file01.txt!
```

This is why many people prefer always to write destination directories with a trailing `/` in `mv`:

```bash
ek@Apok:~/tmp$ mv file03.txt dst/
mv: failed to access 'dst/': Not a directory
```

You can use `mv -i` to ask you before overwriting, or `mv -n` to silently *not* overwrite. Otherwise, `mv` only ask you before overwriting if the destination is a read-only file. One reason to consider this is that it covers other cases, like `mv file01.txt dest/` where you didn't realize `dest/file01.txt` existed and didn't want to overwrite it.

You can also use `-t dest` instead of writing `dest` at the end of the command, e.g., `mv -t dest file*.txt`. This refuses to operate if `dest` is a regular file, regardless of whether or not you write a trailing `/`.

---

Using an automated mechanism to run multiple such commands can gravely compound the problem. For example, *as written* the command `for f in file*.txt; do mv "$f" dest/; done` is needlessly complicated but safe, because if I accidentally specified the file `dst` instead of the directory `dest` (but kept the slash!), it would give me one `mv: failed to access 'dst/': Not a directory` error per file. However, if I omitted the trailing `/`, then it would rename each file to `dst`, *replacing* the previous `dst`, and only the last file would remain.

Similar bad outcomes can be achieved with `find`, including in situations where it *may be* reasonable to use `find` (but differently, and still with extra care). For example, suppose I wanted to move all files matching the glob `file*.txt` in an entire directory tree ([except in `dest` itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)) into the directory `dest`. I might first think to use this:

```bash
find . -path ./dest -prune -o -name 'file*.txt' -exec mv {} dest/ \;  # bad, don't use
```

Because I included a trailing `/`, writing `dest/` instead of `dest`, this wouldn't overwrite a file called `dst` even if I wrote `dst` instead of `dest`. But it has the related problem that it will overwrite files that it has already copied, if files in different parts of the directory tree have the same name. For example, if there's an `a/file01.txt` and a `b/file01.txt`, one will overwrite the other. To avoid that, too, it's better to use something like this:

```bash
find -path ./dest -prune -o -name 'file*.txt' -exec mv -it dest/ {} \;  # okay
```

The other benefit of `-t dir` is that, because it lets you specify the destination directory *before* the items being moved, it's compatible with the `+` form of `-exec`, where multiple items are passed to a command, thereby running fewer commands (often just one):

```bash
find -path ./dest -prune -o -name 'file*.txt' -exec mv -it dest/ {} +  # good
```

In both cases (they're the same except for `\;` vs. `+`) I've also passed the `-i` option to prompt before each operation that would overwrite a file. If you just want to silently skip those, write `n` instead of `i`. If you want to test your `find` commands first, you can write `echo` after `-exec` but before the rest of the command to print what would be run. For example:

```bash
ek@Apok:~/tmp$ find -path ./dest -prune -o -name 'file*.txt' -exec echo mv -it dest/ {} +
mv -it dest/ ./file02.txt ./file06.txt ./file10.txt ./file09.txt ./file01.txt ./file04.txt ./file05.txt ./file07.txt ./file03.txt ./file08.txt
```

(Of course, that's in the original directory I showed, where all the files to moved are in the same location, and thus where `find` is overkill and the most complicated reasonable command to use is `mv -it dest/ file*.txt`.)

Comment: Both answers helped me, but I had to chose this, so much effort thank you both.

Comment: @benberizovsky A simpler approach could be to rely on the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for auto-complete. If pressing it fails to auto-complete the destination directory for you, then the directory does not exist at the destination path. At that point, you should start checking for typos and other details.

Answer (score 8):

No, what you suggest should(!) not be possible. You probably need to look better at the destination.  Use `history` to get a list of previous issued commands.

A couple of things:

- As long as the target location is on the same partition as the source, no data will get moved. Only the name in the directory entry gets changed.

If there IS a move done ...

- See `info coreutils 'mv invocation'` (on-line version https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html#mv-invocation ) for how mv works and more specific this part:

  > It first uses some of the same code that’s used by ‘cp -a’ to
  >   copy the requested directories and files, then (assuming the copy
  >   succeeded) it removes the originals.  If the copy fails, then the part
  >   that was copied to the destination partition is removed.  If you were to
  >   copy three directories from one partition to another and the copy of the
  >   first directory succeeded, but the second didn’t, the first would be
  >   left on the destination partition and the second and third would be left
  >   on the original partition.
- So a move consists of 2 parts:

  1. a `cp -a`
  2. a `mv`

  The removal part of the move is done AFTER there is confirmation the copy has been done correctly.
- if your mv consists of multiple files the copy and move are done in between.  So a

  ```
  mv a b c d e f /dir/
  ```

  will do a

  ```
  cp a /dir/
  rm a
  ...
  cp f /dir/
  rm f
  ```

  so when there is a problem in between a and f it will have finished the move of a and up to where the problem appeared. This also applies to using wildcards.

---

Regarding the edit

```
sudo mv test.txt /ben
```

This moves test.txt to / and renames it to ben. And

```
ben.b@c-w46:~/Desktop/test-folder$ cd /ben
bash: cd: /ben: Not a directory
```

correctly errors out. Do a

```
ls -l /ben
```

and it will show the file.

What you always should do is append a / if you want to move a file to a directory.

```
sudo mv test.txt /ben/
```

would error out as /ben/ does not exists.